# How to make Django create slug from unicode characters?

Tags: django, unicode, slug

Django Unicode Slug how to ?

```
class NewsModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    content = models.TextField()
    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if self.slug is None:
             self.slug = ???
        super(NewsModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("news_view", kwargs = {"slug" : self.slug, } )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Django slugify work properly with Unicode strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702337/how-to-make-django-slugify-work-properly-with-unicode-strings)

Comment: That is worked for my Case. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4036665/489943. Thanks. You answer here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a slug in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837828/how-do-i-create-a-slug-in-django)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django comes with a function for that:

```
In [11]: from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
In [13]: slugify(u'ç é YUOIYO  ___ 89098')
Out[13]: u'c-e-yuoiyo-___-89098'
```

But really your are better off using the [prepopulated_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) parameter and a [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield).

EDIT:

It seems to be a duplicate question, and the answer proposed in the other OP works quite well. First install [unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1), then:

```
In [2]: import unidecode
In [3]: unidecode.unidecode(u"Сайн уу")
Out[3]: 'Sain uu
```

You can pass it to slugify after.

If you are looking for slugs of unicode caractèers, you can use [mozilla/unicode-slugify](https://github.com/mozilla/unicode-slugify)

```
In [1]: import slugify
In [2]: slugify.slugify(u"Сайн уу")
Out[3]: u'\u0441\u0430\u0439\u043d-\u0443\u0443'
```

Result is `http://example.com/news/сайн-уу`

Comment: Very interesting. That is worked. But this is Mongolian unicode characters. wont work slugify(u"Сайн уу")

Comment: Ok, slugify uses unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u"Сайн уу").encode('ascii', 'ignore') to normalize the string, but maybe there is no mapping between Mogolian caracters and ascii. So you'll need to create a mapping yourself and use maketrans (http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) before you pass it to slugify.

Comment: I Found better way. https://github.com/mozilla/unicode-slugify/blob/master/slugify/__init__.py that is very simple and not install any module.

Comment: The mozilla function won't allow you to translate 'й' into a caracter that is suitable for an URL, unless you are aiming for non ASCII URLs.

Comment: 'й' is fine. That worked [here](http://mgleuro.com/public/gallery.html/133276227453-%D1%88%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D3%A9%D0%BC%D0%B1%D3%A9%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B0-mgl-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3-1260664)

Comment: Hence the "unless you are aiming for non ASCII URL " which you didn't mentioned"

Comment: First able i try using standart django slugify function. Finally i understand this non ASCII URL is better for me. My customers can read URL in address bar.

Comment: @Ankhaa  >> and not install any module.  Seems like need to install `unicode-slugify`

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you want to automatically create a slug based on your `NewsModel`'s title, you want to use `slugify`:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
  if self.slug is None:
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
  super(NewsModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: django default slugify not support unicode strings. Example slugify(u"Сайн уу")

Comment: slugify + unicode:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702337/how-to-make-django-slugify-work-properly-with-unicode-strings

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony you mean `unidecode` (not `unicode`)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i am using in my projects. i know this question is for many times ago but i hope my solution help someone.
i should mention that there is a good solution for this in https://github.com/mozilla/unicode-slugify but this is what i use:

```
import re
import unicodedata

try:
    from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode as smart_text
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.encoding import smart_text

def slugify(value):
    #underscore, tilde and hyphen are alowed in slugs
    value = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', smart_text(value))
    prog = re.compile(r'[^~\w\s-]', flags=re.UNICODE)
    value = prog.sub('', value).strip().lower()
    return re.sub(r'[-\s]+', '-', value)
```