# How to slugify while still maintaining UTF-8 letters

Tags: python, django, utf-8, slug

I am trying to slugify UTF-8 text, which in this case involves characters such as æøå, which I want to maintain.

When I use slugify it does not maintain the UTF-8 chars:

```
>>> from slugify import slugify
>>> slugify(u'æsel (øen)')
'aesel-oen'
```

It should be `æsel-øen`.

Comment: Exactly what slugify library are you using here?

Comment: One of the main features of slugifying is to restrict the characters to ASCII.

Comment: And [How to make Django slugify work properly with Unicode strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/702337) also mentions `unicode-slugify`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different library to slugify; the [`unicode-slugify` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicode-slugify) output fits your requirements exactly:

```
$ bin/pip install unicode-slugify
Downloading/unpacking unicode-slugify
  Downloading unicode-slugify-0.1.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/.../build/unicode-slugify/setup.py) egg_info for package unicode-slugify

Downloading/unpacking django (from unicode-slugify)
  Downloading Django-1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4MB): 7.4MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: unicode-slugify, django
  Running setup.py install for unicode-slugify

Successfully installed unicode-slugify django
Cleaning up...
$ bin/python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 19 2014, 22:15:41) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.51)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from slugify import slugify
>>> slugify(u'æsel (øen)')
u'\xe6sel-\xf8en'
>>> print slugify(u'æsel (øen)')
æsel-øen
```