# Slugify and an issue with Persian language

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-models, persian

I have model like following:

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey('profiles.Employee', limit_choices_to={'is_employee': True})
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    detail = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    frequency = models.CharField(choices=freqs, max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}--{}".format(self.business, self.title)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        if not self.title == "":
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Rule, self).save()
```

I don't have any problem with saving English value records in slug but when I wanna save Persian strings I'm encountered with blank field, although I wrote `ALLOW_UNICODE_SLUGS = True` in the `settings.py` file.
What should I do?

Comment: This question should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702337/how-to-make-django-slugify-work-properly-with-unicode-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new option which is being introduced in django version 1.9 is `SlugField.allow_unicode`

If True, the field accepts Unicode letters in addition to ASCII letters. Defaults to False. [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#slugfield)

For example:

In models.py file, define the slug column like below:

```
slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked!
First of all you should install unidecode by Pip:

```
pip install unidecode
```

Or use the following link:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode

After that:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    from unidecode import unidecode
    from django.template import defaultfilters
    if not self.title == "":
        self.slug = defaultfilters.slugify(unidecode(self.title))
    super(rule, self).save()
```

It is not pretty good for Persian(Arabic) language but it works!